# Which built-in mic should I use

Tags: audio-recording

I need to record some audio, but I don't have any of my mics with me. I have a macbook, a samsung Galaxy, and a canon T5 camera. Which device has the best internal mic?

Comment: Which one will be closest to the source ?

Answer (score 1):

Try them all and see for yourself. Ideally test them in a similar scenario to how you expect to be doing the final recording. It can really depend upon the application that you're using them for.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the Samsung Galaxy. The T5 mic is terrible and the macbook would be very difficult to maneuver to use.